# Error using cv2.drawcontours(), with python

Tags: python-3.x

I was applying some code about drawing contours and I got the following error:
 t = cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)

error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\drawing.cpp:2509: error: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints > 0 in function 'cv::drawContours'

can someone tell me what the problem is??

Comment: Are contours empty?

Comment: I am trying to repair the code and include it into the message but the system is very hard I don't know what to do it is difficult to use this system

Comment: import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('00048421.bmp', 0)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img, 5)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,8,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
t = cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))
plt.imshow(thresh)
plt.show()

Answer (score 0):

It is hard so say because you did not use the code editor.... But I guess it comes from

```
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,8,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
t = cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
```

There is missing findContours function. The contours object is empty so far.
Before drawing you need to find them.
https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html